# Simplenews adds newsletters title at the top of the newsletter

Tags: 7, emails

I have a Drupal-7 site and a testing one and a weird thing happens. When I send a newsletter from my testing site everything is ok, but when I send from the actual site, the title of the newsletter is added at the top of the newsletter. So the newsletter appears like this:
**Title**
Title
images , which is what I want to only appear.

Another weird thing that happens, is that the title appears only at some emails like outlook, but not on gmail or hotmail.

My question is, why do you think that this happens?Do I have to check my administrator options, or is this a code issue, like at simplenews.module file?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find `simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php` in `modules/simplenews/theme` folder.
Copy it to your current theme's folder and open/edit it. You'll see that it has a `$title` variable printed at the top. Comment it out and clear cache to make Drupal see your template change. Test and see the title gone.

```
REMOVE OR COMMENT THIS LINE =>  <h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
<?php print render($build); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had actually made that change at my testing site, but I forgot to change it at my live site too! But that was the way to do it anyway!